# stuck with requirement 3? no velocity or time and i should get distance travelled. any ideas?

Tags: linear-algebra, mathematical-physics

requirement number 3 troubling me, kind of confused should I get the second derivative will do it or dividing max height of the bullet over the max horizontal distance I got from the past 2 steps?
the problem as follows:
a bullet is shot from a submarine which is stationary on the sea level. the path of the bullet above the sea level can be modelled by the function **V=-x^2+100x-1600** where V m represents the height of the bullet above the sea level, and the *x* m represents the horizontal distance of the bullet from an observer.

(a) Find *x* when **V** attains its maximum

(b) Hence, show that the maximum height of the bullet above the sea level is 900 m

(c) Find the horizontal distance of the bullet travelled above the sea level

i solved as follow:

(a) the first derivative of the equation = 0

the first derivative = -2x+100

-2x+100 = 0

-2x = -100

*x* = 50 m

(b) **V***max* = -(50)^2+100(50)-1600 = 900 m

(c) i'm kinda puzzeled
should i get the second derivative which will leave me with -2 and it will
be the answer

**or**

divide **V***max* over *x* of the max height = 900/50 = 18

**or**

solve the original equation **V=-x^2+100x-1600** where **V** is 0
so x will be either 20 or 80 and we accept 20 m as it's smaller than
***X max*** and the solution will be *x*=20 ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dc2eO.jpg)

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  It is **irrelevant** whether the problem is homework.  What counts is whether the protocol is observed.  See also the **Edit-Images** section of the article.

Comment: Also, re last comment, it was unclear (at least to me) what you were asking.  Please try to make your posting so crystal clear that the MathSE reviewers will not be confused as to what you are asking.

Comment: Assuming that I am interpreting the problem correctly, and assuming that your part (c) calculations are correct, the bullet is above the sea level in the range $20 \leq x \leq 80.$  This implies that for the entire time that the bullet was above sea level, the variable $x$ increased in value by $(80 - 20) = 60.$  Again, if I am interpreting the problem correctly, the bullet traveled a horizontal distance of $60$, **while** it was above sea level.